# Resolução de problema em botões de ações na tabela de listagem

Tags: php

Estou com um pequeno problema de ajustar corretamente os botões de ações de UPDATE e DELETE para serem visto na listagem (estam muito juntos quero dar um espaço entre eles). Os botões estão juntos e quando eu clico no botão Atualizar ou Deletar não identifica o registro listado não identifica

[image]

- Código

```
<?php
    require_once "../model/MangaDAO.php";
    $manga = new MangaDAO();
    foreach ($manga->selectAllMangas() as $valor){
       echo '<tr>';
           echo '<td title="'.$valor['id_manga'].'">'.$valor['id_manga'].'</td>';
           echo '<td title="'.$valor['titulo'].'">'.$valor['titulo'].'</td>';
           echo '<td title="'.$valor['editora'].'">'.$valor['editora'].'</td>';
           echo '<td title="'.$valor['volumes'].'">'.$valor['volumes'].'</td>';
           echo '<td title="R$'.$valor['desconto'].'">R$'.$valor['desconto'].'</td>';
           echo '<td title="R$'.$valor['valor'].'">R$'.$valor['valor'].'</td>';
           echo '<td title="'.date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($valor['data_cadastro'])).'">'.
           date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($valor['data_cadastro'])).'</td>';
           echo '<td>'.'<a class="btn btn-info" title="Atualizar" href="/mangas/view/form_update_manga.php?id_manga=<?php echo $id_manga ?>" 
role="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Atualizar</a>'.'<a class="btn btn-danger" title="Deletar" href="/mangas/controller/delete_manga.php?id_manga=<?php echo $id_manga ?>" role="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Deletar</a>'.'</td>';                       
           echo '</tr>'; 
           echo '</p>';
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
require_once "../model/MangaDAO.php";
$manga = new MangaDAO();
foreach ($manga->selectAllMangas() as $valor){
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td title="'.$valor['id_manga'].'">'.$valor['id_manga'].'</td>';
    echo '<td title="'.$valor['titulo'].'">'.$valor['titulo'].'</td>';
    echo '<td title="'.$valor['editora'].'">'.$valor['editora'].'</td>';
    echo '<td title="'.$valor['volumes'].'">'.$valor['volumes'].'</td>';
    echo '<td title="R$'.$valor['desconto'].'">R$'.$valor['desconto'].'</td>';
    echo '<td title="R$'.$valor['valor'].'">R$'.$valor['valor'].'</td>';
    echo '<td title="'.date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($valor['data_cadastro'])).'">'.
    date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($valor['data_cadastro'])).'</td>';
    echo '<td>';
    echo ' <a class="btn btn-info" title="Atualizar" '
            . 'href="/mangas/view/form_update_manga.php?id_manga='. $id_manga.'" role="button"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>&nbsp;Atualizar</a>';
    echo ' <a class="btn btn-danger" title="Deletar" '
            . ' href="/mangas/controller/delete_manga.php?id_manga='.$id_manga.'" role="button"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>&nbsp;Deletar</a>';
    echo '</td>';                       
    echo '</tr>';
```

}
?>

Comment: Os botões ainda estam juntos, parece que o ```&nbsp;``` não fez efeito.